# How to return the intersection of column and row in Python?

Tags: python, sql, flask, intersection

noob here!

I would like to know what is the proper way to return the intersection of a row and column (both inputs) from a table in Python. Basically the equivalent of what you can do with MATCH and INDEX in Excel. [This is part of the table in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAa1i.png). Using the picture as example the inputs would be a Series value, a Size value and one of the codes from the header of the columns and it should return the proper "EZ-..." matching code.

I have basic knowledge in Python and SQL, so if the answer is using any or both of these languages would be preferable.

I think one way to do it is to query in SQL but one column has to be a variable (the code in column header), tried to find how to do that but no luck yet.

Thanks in advance for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pandas` library ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/)) provides an excellent set of tools for problems such as yours:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read data
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel/file.xlsx')

# Alternatively: Mock data for reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'series': ['FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP'], 
    'size': ['1/4"', '3/8"', '1/2"', '3/4"', '1"'],
    '70003': ['EZ-001D-3C', 'EZ-002D-3C', 'EZ-003D-3C', 'EZ-004D-3C', 'EZ-005D-C'],
    '70005': ['EZ-006D-3C', 'EZ-007D-3C', 'EZ-008D-3C', 'EZ-009D-3C', 'EZ-010D-3C'],
    '70006': ['EZ-011D-3C', 'EZ-012D-3C', 'EZ-013D-3C', 'EZ-014D-3C', 'EZ-015D-3C']
    })

# Example values
series_value = 'FP'
size = '1/4"'
column_code = '70003'

# Subset dataframe and select series (column) corresponding to column_code
result_series = df[(df['series'] == series_value) & (df['size'] == size)][column_code]

# Retrieve cell value
result_value = result_series.to_list()[0]
print(result_value)

# Result will be 'EZ-001D-3C'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at pandas library as suggested, looks like the proper way to tackle this issue.

However, in the meantime I managed to solve the problem with sqlite3 by creating a new table for my current db with the information shown and query the column from a variable, something like this:


`act_data = db.execute("SELECT (%s) FROM KITELEC WHERE PN = ?" %("`" + act_size + "`"), (val_pn,))`

Where act_size is the code (70003, 70005, etc) so the column is dynamically selected depending on the variable.